# How to retrieve data from Laravel cache for Laravel media library package

Tags: php, laravel, caching, media-library

When posts create, I upload a photo using Laravel media library and I can simply retrieve data from media library using:

```
$blog->getFirstMediaUrl('blog');
```

I use Laravel cache feature for best performance and minimum query with `redis`. I stored blog data in cache like below:

```
$blogs=Blog::where('publication_status', 1)
->select('id', 'admin_id', 'category_id', 'sub_category_id', 
'blog_section_id', 'blog_title', 'slug',
'blog_short_description', 'blog_long_description', 'author_name',
'thumbnail', 'publication_status', 'created_at')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->get();

Cache::forever('blogs', $blogs);
```

At that time I cached media library photo also like below:

```
$media=Media::all(); Cache::forever('media', $media);
```

After that I retrieved my blogs data in frontend like below:

```
$data['blogs']=cache()-get('blogs', function (){
    Blog::where('publication_status', 1)
    ->select('id', 'admin_id', 'category_id', 'sub_category_id', 'blog_section_id', 'blog_title', 'slug',
    'blog_short_description', 'blog_long_description', 'author_name',
    'thumbnail', 'publication_status', 'created_at')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
});

return view('Frontend.includes.homepage.homepage', $data);
```

and pass $data in view file like below:

```
<div class="single_post_content_left">
    <ul class="business_catgnav  wow fadeInDown">
        @foreach($blogs
        ->where('thumbnail', 1)
        ->where('blog_section_id', 1)
        ->take(1)
        as $main_section)

        <li>
            <figure class="bsbig_fig"> <a href="{{ route('article', $main_section->slug) }}" class="featured_img"> <img alt="" src="{{
                $main_section->getFirstMediaUrl('blog') }}"> <span
                class="overlay"></span> </a>

                <figcaption> <a href="{{ route('article', $main_section->slug) }}">{{ $main_section->blog_title }}</a>
                </figcaption>
                <p>{{ $main_section->blog_short_description }}</p>
            </figure>
        </li>

        <small class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $main_section->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>

        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here blogs are retrieve from cache successfully without media library data:

```
$main_section->getFirstMediaUrl('blog');
```

But I want to retrieve my media library data from cache like blogs for minimum query run, what can I do?

Comment: For future reference, use 4 spaces to indent code, don't use `>` at the beginning of each line, as that is for highlighting text.